# Redim of Public Array Within Class Results in Loss of Dimensions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I am using Redim in a class on a two-dimensional array that is defined as public in a "declarations" module.  However, depending on where the program flow is after the Redim, there can be a loss of dimensions.  The pattern is that when I instantiate another object (class) within this class, then run the small process in that new object and come back the dimensions of the public array are lower.  Thus if the new object was never instantiated to go out and do work, the results are confirmed that loss of elements doesn't occur.

For my example, the Redim is A(20,1) but after using the instantiated class to do a small outside job (outside of this class we are in -->with the Redim) the dimensions are A(19,0).

There are rules for Redim based on where it is used, so my question is how can I retain declaring a public array in a declaration module, and then use Redim on those arrays within instantiated objects (classes) without losing dimensions?

Below is example code, that will cause this issue:

```
Module mymod()
   Public A(,) As single
End Module

In button 1:
Dim obj as New Test

Class Test
  Sub New
     Call mytest()
  End Sub

  Sub mytest()
    Redim A(20,1)
    'Here is where A will have dimensions (20,1)
     Dim myobj as As New ClassB
    'Here is where A will have dimensions (19,0)
  End Sub
End Class

Class ClassB
  Sub New()
    Msgbox("hello")
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you determining that the dimensions have changed?

I modified the code to this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim obj As New Test
    End Sub

End Class

Module mymod
    Public A(,) As Single
End Module

Class Test

    Sub New()
        Call mytest()
    End Sub

    Sub mytest()
        ReDim A(20, 1)
        'Here is where A will have dimensions (20,1)
        Debug.Print("Before...")
        Debug.Print("Lower = " & A.GetLowerBound(0))
        Debug.Print("Upper = " & A.GetUpperBound(0))
        Dim myobj As New ClassB
        'Here is where A will have dimensions (19,0)
        Debug.Print("After...")
        Debug.Print("Lower = " & A.GetLowerBound(0))
        Debug.Print("Upper = " & A.GetUpperBound(0))
    End Sub

End Class

Class ClassB
    Sub New()
        Msgbox("hello")
    End Sub
End Class
```

And got this output:

```
Before...
Lower = 0
Upper = 20
After...
Lower = 0
Upper = 20
```

Comment: Thanks, very instructive comments. I identified that an array redimension was not occurring after a dimension size variable was set.